# want to plot stacked or different facets showing each of the column

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, stack, facet

In the R program, I want to plot a stacked bar plot or plot with facets showing as many as the number of the columns.

for the stacked bar plot, I have this data in excel, given in Table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPnMK.png):

Table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPnMK.png)

Code is below to plot stacked bar:

```
x3<- read.xlsx("D:\\R\\phenology.xlsx", sheet = 1)
x1=x3$Years
print(x1)
df <-data.frame(Years  = x3$Years,
            PI = x3$`Panicle.initiation.days.(Days)`,
            AD= x3$`Anthesis.days.(Days)`,
            MD = x3$`Maturity.days.(Days)`)
print(df)
Phenology <-data.frame(PI = x3$`Panicle.initiation.days.(Days)`,
            AD= x3$`Anthesis.days.(Days)`,
            MD = x3$`Maturity.days.(Days)`)
print(Phenology)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= Years, y = Phenology)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity', col = "green")
```

***For various facets with number of columns I am using this code":

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= Years, y = Phenology,fill = PI & AD & MD)) 
+geom_bar() + facet_grid(~PI & AD & MD)
```

It would be helpful if I could get suggestions to resolve the issue on these two codes in  R.

Comment: Please include data along with your question so that the issue can be reproduced. Consider using `dput(df)` instead of posting the images.

Comment: Data given in Table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

First and important bring your data in long format!
This is important due to different reasons and not scope of this question:

You do this with `pivot_longer`. If you do not determine `names_to` and `values_to` you will get `name` and `value` as default column name.

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

you could for example do

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
   -Years # the column not to reshaped
   names_to = "my desired column name", 
   values_to = "my desired value name"
  )...
```

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Years
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Years), y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is what I wanted. Could you please elaborate on how did you create "name" and "value".

Comment: Please see my update!